# Array in loop in TCSH shell

Tags: arrays, list, shell, loops, tcsh

In TCSH :

I'm giving two lists containing different files in it. Then I have to pass those list as an array element and then the loop should execute twice as there are only 2 lists. But in this case loop is executing as much time as those files in both the lists.

```
set list_one = (one.s two.s three.s)
set list_two = (four.s five.s)

set arr=($list_one $list_two)

foreach i ($arr)
cat $i > $output.s

end
```

This is an example of my code, according to me loop should execute only twice(for list_one and list_two), but it's executing five times (for one.s two.s three.s four.s five.s)

If I use like this (mentioned below), loop executes for two times. But at **cat** command I get an error as, **No such file or directory** for each list that I passed in array.

```
set arr=(list_one list_two)

foreach i ($arr)
cat $i > $output.s
end
```

Comment: Please [format your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) properly for better readability.

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track with your second approach, only a level of variable substitution was missing.

```
set arr=(list_one list_two)
foreach i ($arr)
    eval cat \$$i >$output.s
end
```